# Structure values being overwritten during execution

Tags: c#, structure, unmanaged, ushort

I have structure defined below:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 10)]
public struct AudioSampleInfo
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ushort AudioBitPerSample;

    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public ushort AudioNumChannels;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public ushort AudioType;

    [FieldOffset(6)]
    public uint AudioSampleRate;
}
```

However, during execution the values seem to change.
It seems as if the assigned byte array in memory seem to be overlapping.

During program execution when we set the values as:

```
AudioSampleInfo audioInfo = new AudioSampleInfo();
audioInfo.AudioBitPerSample = 16;
audioInfo.AudioNumChannels = 1;
```

After setting the `AudioNumChannels`, value of `AudioBitsPerSample` changes to 272.

I can't seem to find any issues as to why this would be occur .

Any suggestions would be helpful ?

Comment: Doesn't happen when I try it... You sure this repro works?

Comment: Not reproduced. It is working fine.

Comment: I'm still investigating as to why this occurs on my end.